# Problems with Bitbtn in Delphi 6 under Windows vista

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, delphi-6

I've been working for a long time under Windows XP with Delphi 6 (and under Win2k before).
As I've recently bought a new laptop, I had to start using Windows Vista.

I've installed Delphi 6. Whenever I used the TBitBtn component, I get error when running the compiled program: like  resource BBOK not found, resource BBcancel not found, etc.

"Project Project1.exe raised exception class EReadError with message 'Error reading BitBtn1.Kind: Resource BBCANCEL not found'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue."

Right now, I do not have possibility to try to run the exe-file on WinXP; however I was able to compile the same code under WinXP and the produced executable ran fine under Windows Vista as well.

Is there some simple workaround other than upgrade to a newer version of Delphi?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't call "upgrading to a newer version of Delphi" a workaround. It is just "eliminating the cause of the problem".

Comment: i'd get resource editon and check out if those bitmap really not found.

Comment: @Uwe I'll do it if I have to, but I am afraid some problems might come with using things I programmed in Delphi 6.
@user Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried some resource editor and found out that there is no bitmap BBOK in the executable, but it contains QBOK.

Comment: First, @Uwe, we don't know whether a different version will really eliminate the cause. And even if it does, unless we have *identified* the cause, upgrading still feels like a workaround.

Comment: @Rob, its only my opinion, but running a 10yr old app on a modern OS is just asking for trouble. Even if you identify the cause for this specific problem your are just stepping on to the next one. I'm not using D6 by myself, but D5 as well as D7 and D2007 - in a VM with XP.

Comment: @Uwe Nonsense, I happily run D6 on 64 bit Win7, alongside D2010. The compatibility from MS is excellent, as it has been for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a very neat solution, but this issue seems working after:

- Copying Buttons.pas and buttons.res from Sources\Vcl to the directory with my project.
- Editing Buttons.pas to use QBOK, QBCANCEL etc. instead of BBOK, BBCANCEL.

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The QB resources come from the CLX controls, which you should never use in a VCL program. Did you accidentally use the QButtons unit or one of the other "Q" units? (As I understand it, the help can be confusing because it doesn't always make clear that some useful functions are only available with CLX, not VCL.) If those resources are getting linked into your project, then it sounds like you have some search paths wrong, or else some Delphi files are in the wrong places. You shouldn't have to recompile the stock Buttons.pas.

Comment: Rob is right, you almost surely have included a Q unit somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will probably work with this as a temporary solution, since I am unable to find the problem you mention at the moment. I hope I'll find it eventually.